# issue with Xamarin form grid inside Stacklayout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms Where i need to display grid. I am using `StackLayout` to create form. Everything is working until I add Grid inside `StackLayout` ., then I am  getting error that `Timeout exceeded getting exception details`

Here is my code :

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White">
            <StackLayout Padding="20,40,20,0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Image Source="logo.png" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Image>
            </StackLayout>


            <StackLayout Padding="15,20,15,0" VerticalOptions="Center">

                <local:ImageEntry TextColor="#98a4b4" 
                                  PlaceholderColor="#98a4b4" FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                                  Image="LoginEmailIcon" 
                                  Placeholder="Email" 
                                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                  ImageWidth="25"
                                  ImageHeight="20"
                                  LineColor="#98a4b4"/>


                <local:ImageEntry TextColor="#98a4b4" 
                                  PlaceholderColor="#98a4b4" FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                                  Image="LoginPasswordIcon" 
                                  Placeholder="Password" 
                                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                  ImageWidth="23"
                                  ImageHeight="25"
                                  LineColor="#98a4b4" IsPassword="True"/>
                <Label  Text=" Forgot your password?"
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                        TextColor="#bcbcbc"/>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="ButtonSignin" BackgroundColor="#29abdf" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontFamily="ProximaNova" Text="Sign in" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="25px" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="loginsideicon.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Image>
                        <Label Text="OR" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="ProximaNova" TextColor="#bcbcbc"></Label>
                        <Image Source="loginsideicon.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"></Image>
                    </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Now When I run this code I am getting exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.FormatException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> occurred
```

But when i comment Grid code everything is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed a few issues with your xaml :

-Use a capital letter for **Auto**

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
```

-We do not use 25**px** with xaml

`<RowDefinition Height="25" />`